# UIImagePicker allowsEditing stuck in center

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePicker that works perfect for a type of UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary, but when I use UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera, the editing box cannot move from the center of the image. So if the image is say taller than it is wide, the user cannot move the editing box to the top square of the image.

Anyone know why this would be the case? It only happens when the source is from the camera, not the library.

Edit: Some CODE!!!

```
if (actionSheet.tag == 2) {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) { // Camera
        // Check for camera
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == YES) {
            // Create image picker controller
            UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

            // Set source to the camera
            imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

            // Delegate is self
            imagePicker.delegate = self;

            // Show image picker
            [self presentViewController:imagePicker 
                               animated:YES 
                             completion:^(void) {
                             }];
        }
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) { // Photo Library
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary] == YES) {
            // Create image picker controller
            UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

            // Set source to the camera
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

            // Delegate is self
            imagePicker.delegate = self;

            // Show image picker
            [self presentViewController:imagePicker 
                               animated:YES 


                          completion:^(void) {
                                 }];
            }
}
```

So as you can see, I display them the exact same, but the camera edit acts differently than the photo library edit.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Looks like this behavior is just a bug in iOS 6... Basically you cannot move the editing box, it always bounces back to the middle unless you zoom in a bit. Hopefully they fix that soon.

Comment: I think this is still a bug in iOS 7

Comment: aaaand still a bug in iOS 8.  :(

Comment: Same bug exists in even iOS 8.1

Comment: I'm from the future, still a bug in iOS 12.0

Comment: I cant believe this is still an issue, come on Apple!

Comment: Still a bug in iOS 9. Did anyone find a solution?

Comment: Confirmed, still stuck in iOS 9.1

Comment: Still stuck in iOS 9.2. I can't get allowsEditing/cropping to work properly for choosing existing photos or taking new ones. Apple obviously LOVES their developers.

Comment: Has anyone filed this at bugreport.apple.com? Apple tracks bugs in Radar, not StackOverflow. ;-) Expecting it to get fixed without reporting it is sure to be an exercise in frustration.

Comment: Still having this bug in iOS 10 :(

Comment: Still having this bug today. :(((

Comment: @QuinnTaylor this ticket was raised in 2012. Expecting anything to get fixed even with a ticket is definitely an exercise in frustration. http://openradar.appspot.com/12318774 I added this again two months ago... http://openradar.appspot.com/28260087 ... and haven't heard anything. Although, getting feedback from radars is something I've learned doesn't happen. So, seeing as there has been a ticket for the last four years... when can we expect it to be fixed? Thanks

Comment: iOS 10.2 Hello bug! When pick from album - everything works.

Comment: I wonder if @QuinnTaylor or anyone from the Apple Dev team is going to break from the norm and actually let us know what is going on with this? Is 5 years enough time for them to fix a fairly simple but serious bug? Would've thought so...???

Comment: Radio silence from @QuinnTaylor... the usual Apple response. :(

Comment: @Fogmeister Despite the fact that you're asking me directly, I'm not on the team that can fix this bug. It's not my place or responsibility to comment on status or schedule for bugs. I'm trying to get traction on it internally, but please don't expect to get updates along the way.

Comment: https://imgflip.com/memetemplate/Ill-Just-Wait-Here waiting for it to work, still waiting.

Comment: OK, just tried in iOS 11... it is still broken :( FFS... come on Apple.

Comment: What about iOS 20.0 @BrentDillingham

Comment: 2 more weeks until we find out that Apple still hasn't done anything about this.

Comment: Still a bug for the iOS 13.0 beta :D

Comment: iOS 13.5 still a bug! :D

Comment: iOS 14.3 - still an issue :)

Comment: I just testing in iOS 15 and........... IT'S FIXED! But also... UIImagePickerViewController now crashes when you try to search and also it's being replaced by PHPickerViewController.... which also crashes when you try to search. LOL! 

Comment: still an issue in iOS 16

Answer (score 4):

Thanks [yycking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3282496/yycking). This [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53440254/7760418) works. Except I added the method call inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` so that I don't have to call it every time I want to open image picker.

Here's the full extenstion

```
extension UIImagePickerController {
    open override var childForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }

    open override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    open override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        fixCannotMoveEditingBox()
    }
    
    func fixCannotMoveEditingBox() {
            if let cropView = cropView,
               let scrollView = scrollView,
               scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0 {
                
                var top: CGFloat = 0.0
                if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                    top = cropView.frame.minY + self.view.safeAreaInsets.top
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                    top = cropView.frame.minY
                }
                let bottom = scrollView.frame.height - cropView.frame.height - top
                scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: top, left: 0, bottom: bottom, right: 0)
                
                var offset: CGFloat = 0
                if scrollView.contentSize.height > scrollView.contentSize.width {
                    offset = 0.5 * (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.contentSize.width)
                }
                scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -top + offset)
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { [weak self] in
                self?.fixCannotMoveEditingBox()
            }
        }
        
        var cropView: UIView? {
            return findCropView(from: self.view)
        }
        
        var scrollView: UIScrollView? {
            return findScrollView(from: self.view)
        }
        
        func findCropView(from view: UIView) -> UIView? {
            let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
            let size = view.bounds.size
            if width == size.height, width == size.height {
                return view
            }
            for view in view.subviews {
                if let cropView = findCropView(from: view) {
                    return cropView
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
        
        func findScrollView(from view: UIView) -> UIScrollView? {
            if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView {
                return scrollView
            }
            for view in view.subviews {
                if let scrollView = findScrollView(from: view) {
                    return scrollView
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reset `contentInset` of `scrollview`:

```
extension UIImagePickerController {
    func fixCannotMoveEditingBox() {
        if let cropView = cropView,
           let scrollView = scrollView,
           scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0 {
            
            let top = cropView.frame.minY + self.view.safeAreaInsets.top
            let bottom = scrollView.frame.height - cropView.frame.height - top
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: top, left: 0, bottom: bottom, right: 0)
            
            var offset: CGFloat = 0
            if scrollView.contentSize.height > scrollView.contentSize.width {
                offset = 0.5 * (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.contentSize.width)
            }
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -top + offset)
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { [weak self] in
            self?.fixCannotMoveEditingBox()
        }
    }
    
    var cropView: UIView? {
        return findCropView(from: self.view)
    }
    
    var scrollView: UIScrollView? {
        return findScrollView(from: self.view)
    }
    
    func findCropView(from view: UIView) -> UIView? {
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let size = view.bounds.size
        if width == size.height, width == size.height {
            return view
        }
        for view in view.subviews {
            if let cropView = findCropView(from: view) {
                return cropView
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    func findScrollView(from view: UIView) -> UIScrollView? {
        if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView {
            return scrollView
        }
        for view in view.subviews {
            if let scrollView = findScrollView(from: view) {
                return scrollView
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

then call it

```
imagePickercontroller.fixCannotMoveEditingBox()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an extension I end up using that works fine on both notch and non-notch devices. And works perfectly on iOS 15!

```
extension UIImagePickerController {
    open override var childForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }

    open override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    open override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        fixCannotMoveEditingBox()
    }
    
    private func fixCannotMoveEditingBox() {
        if let cropView = cropView, let scrollView = scrollView, scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0 {
            let top: CGFloat = cropView.frame.minY + self.view.frame.minY
            let bottom = scrollView.frame.height - cropView.frame.height - top
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: top, left: 0, bottom: bottom, right: 0)
            
            var offset: CGFloat = 0
            if scrollView.contentSize.height > scrollView.contentSize.width {
                offset = 0.5 * (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.contentSize.width)
            }
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -top + offset)
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { [weak self] in
            self?.fixCannotMoveEditingBox()
        }
    }
    
    private var cropView: UIView? {
        return findCropView(from: self.view)
    }
    
    private var scrollView: UIScrollView? {
        return findScrollView(from: self.view)
    }
    
    private func findCropView(from view: UIView) -> UIView? {
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let size = view.bounds.size
        if width == size.height, width == size.height {
            return view
        }
        for view in view.subviews {
            if let cropView = findCropView(from: view) {
                return cropView
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    private func findScrollView(from view: UIView) -> UIScrollView? {
        if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView {
            return scrollView
        }
        for view in view.subviews {
            if let scrollView = findScrollView(from: view) {
                return scrollView
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

---

p.s.: the only changes from other similar answers are:

- dropping support for an old iOS version (like iOS 11);
- a bit different way of calculating contentInset top property;

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior the Image Picker Controller, you can not change it.  The only other option is to create your own cropping utility.  Check out the link below for an example:

https://github.com/ardalahmet/SSPhotoCropperViewController

Comment: But it works when you pick from an album.. Doesn't make sense. Why would you be able to move it more when its from an album rather than camera

Comment: @Eric the editing box does not move at all, it is fixed in the middle of the screen, and you are able to scale the picture to fit in the box.  Take a screenshot, because your code is right

Comment: Ill add a screen shot as soon as I can but what I mean is the static box stays still (which is correct), but the image underneath that moves cannot be moved so the edit box is in the top area of the image. If you scroll to that area the image 'bounces back' to the center of the image...

Comment: this isnt the default behaviour, i believe it is a bug in ios6. On previous ios versions it works fine, but on ios6 the image bounces back when you try and move it. However it does work slightly if you zoom in a bit.

Comment: @Robert Oh ok.. That's what I figured! I guess I will just let it be until they update it..

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is not a good solution, but it works.

I tested on iOS8+iPhone5, iOS9+iPhone6sPlus, iOS10+iPhone6, iOS10+iPhone6sPlus.

**CAUTION**: `PLImageScrollView` and `PLCropOverlayCropView` are **UNDOCUMENTED** classes.

```
- (void)showImagePickerControllerWithSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [UIImagePickerController new];
    imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:^{
        [self fxxxImagePickerController:imagePickerController];
    }];
}

- (void)fxxxImagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePickerController {
    if (!imagePickerController
        || !imagePickerController.allowsEditing
        || imagePickerController.sourceType != UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
        return;
    }

    // !!!: UNDOCUMENTED CLASS
    Class ScrollViewClass = NSClassFromString(@"PLImageScrollView");
    Class CropViewClass = NSClassFromString(@"PLCropOverlayCropView");

    [imagePickerController.view eachSubview:^BOOL(UIView *subview, NSInteger depth) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:CropViewClass]) {
            // 0. crop rect position
            subview.frame = subview.superview.bounds;
        }
        else if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]
            && [subview isKindOfClass:ScrollViewClass]) {
            BOOL isNewImageScrollView = !self->_imageScrollView;
            self->_imageScrollView = (UIScrollView *)subview;
            // 1. enable scrolling
            CGSize size = self->_imageScrollView.frame.size;
            CGFloat inset = ABS(size.width - size.height) / 2;
            self->_imageScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(inset, 0, inset, 0);
            // 2. centering image by default
            if (isNewImageScrollView) {
                CGSize contentSize = self->_imageScrollView.contentSize;
                if (contentSize.height > contentSize.width) {
                    CGFloat offset = round((contentSize.height - contentSize.width) / 2 - inset);
                    self->_imageScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self->_imageScrollView.contentOffset.x, offset);
                }
            }
        }
        return YES;
    }];

    // prevent re-layout, maybe not necessary
    @weakify(self, imagePickerController);
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        @strongify(self, imagePickerController);
        [self fxxxImagePickerController:imagePickerController];
    });
}
```

---

**EDIT**: The `eachSubview:` method traverses all the subviews tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO in info.plist and set status bar appearance as light using

```
 UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

or using any other method , Then simply set the style as .default before presenting the image picker. for Eg:

```
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Change the source type according to your need either as *photoLibrary or camera* and in completion block of your **didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo** add the following to completion block.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    //let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    var pickedImage : UIImage?
    if let img = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    {
        pickedImage = img

    }
    else if let img = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
        pickedImage = img
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle         = .lightContent
    })}
```

Apparently this is a workaround for the same.Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

A workaround that solved it is to add an entry in info.plist with "**View controller-based status bar appearance**" set to NO