# Can't pan image taken from camera with UIImagePicker

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using a UIImagePicker to get the user to take a photo. When the photo is taken, I want them to pan and zoom the image around to fit inside the cropped box so that the image is stored as a square.

However, when cropping the image, it seems as though you cannot move it to the top and bottom of a (portrait) image (left and right if landscape).

I have tried searching but there doesn't seem to be much information, but it seems like a massive issue.

Can someone help?

This is the very small amount of code I'm using:

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera

present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

There's obviously more code but this is the main part.

EDIT with photo:

[image]

So I want to be able to move the photo around/zoom in to select any square portion to save. However, I cannot move it from this position/ keeps snapping back.

I can zoom in, but it still restricts me from the top and bottom edges.

Again, it works with the photoLibrary.

Comment: let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            myPickerController.delegate = self;
             myPickerController.allowsEditing = true
   myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            self.presentViewController(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Are you just telling me to set the delegate to self? Because I've already done that

Comment: are you checking in which device ? iphone 6 or else ?

Comment: It only needs to work for iPhone 5S

Comment: then in iphone 5s i never face that kind of problem .one suggestion is that remove your app from your device and then clean your project and run it again and check this issue again.

Comment: Still having the same issue.

Comment: This has been a bug since iOS 6, and it does not look like they're gonna fix it for some reason. I recommend using an alternative, as https://github.com/justwudi/WDImagePicker for example. Also look at this post back from 2012, with the same exact bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630155/uiimagepicker-allowsediting-stuck-in-center

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya lol. Have you tried it? It is a bug hat has existed since ios6. Just try it before claiming it works for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UIImagePicker allowsEditing stuck in center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630155/uiimagepicker-allowsediting-stuck-in-center)

Answer (score 9):

This is a bug that was introduced in iOS 6 and hasn't been fixed yet.

A radar was raised in 2012 for this but closed by Apple. I managed to get it opened again and have been pestering Apple devs in my contacts for the past 6 months.

http://openradar.appspot.com/12318774

Until this is fixed by Apple the only option is to use a third party control or do it yourself.

Here is the radar I opened...

http://openradar.appspot.com/28260087

Comment: Wow. The original radar was opened in 2012 and the bug still exists today in 2021. "File a radar!" what a joke

Comment: Still not working in iPhone 13, iOS 15.4.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said it already zooms but you may just need to adjust the bounds for that.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    image.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You may also need to use CGRect to set the image correctly in the screen. It should be centered. If you are using and iphone 5 the dimensions 640 x 1136.

This happens because the width or the height of the image gets maxed out to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the solution provided at below link:-

https://github.com/Hipo/HIPImageCropper

It handles the landscape and potrait allignment of the image and provides zoom in and zoom out with crop functionality.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO in info.plist and set status bar appearance as light using

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

or using any other method , Then simply set the style as .default before presenting the image picker. for Eg:

```
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Change the source type according to your need either as photoLibrary or camera and in completion block of your didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo add the following to completion block.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    //let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    var pickedImage : UIImage?
    if let img = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    {
        pickedImage = img

    }
    else if let img = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
        pickedImage = img
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle         = .lightContent
    })}
```

Apparently this is a workaround for the same.Hope this helps.

Comment: This gave us hope but it doesn't seem to work. If anyone solved the issue by using this workaround, please let fellow coders know.