# imagePickerController editing, unable to pan the image

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, crop

In my project I have used `self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true`  for image cropping. When image taken from gallery it is working fine I can move the image through the rectangle but when image taken directly from camera it is unable to pan image, user can select only the area which appear first time in that rectangle.Like in the given picture top and bottom area can not be selected.

```
self.imagePicker.allowsEditing      =   true
self.imagePicker.sourceType         =   .camera
self.imagePicker.mediaTypes         =   ["public.image"]
self.imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode  =   .photo
self.imagePicker.sourceType         =   UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post whole image picker configuration for Camera?

Comment: Sure, I made an edit in the question.

Comment: I checked your code and tried at my end it's working for me Can you tell me on which iOS version you're testing this?

Comment: iOS 13.5, I am not able to select the potions from top and bottom. Otherwise crop is working fine.

Comment: I think that's the default one its same for all the iPhones & iOS.

Comment: iOS 15.4. Same issue. Did anyone get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found. From another thread.

[A bug in iOS from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41870277/5967144), still not fixed! What a pitty!!