# UIImagePickerController crop rectangle won't move

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm having trouble editing (cropping) image after capturing it using UIImagePickerController.

Here is the code I use to invoke UIImagePickerController:

```
  let picker = UIImagePickerController()

  self.picker.allowsEditing = true
  self.picker.sourceType = .camera
  self.present(self.picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But during editing stage, crop rectangle refuses to move, it just jumps back to the original position.

If I set `picker.sourceType = .camera` and proceed to editing, everything is fine and cropping works perfectly.

Have anyone encountered such behavior of UIImagePickerController?

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13167122/3901620

Comment: This is a bug that has existed since iOS 6 but for some reason Apple decided to ignore it for 4 years.