# UIImagePicker Giving Wrong Cropped Image In Objective c and Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, crop

I have used this below code to open UIImagePickerView.

```
 UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker.delegate = self;
 picker.allowsEditing = YES;
 picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
 [self.view presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I have just get cropped image from didfinish method of UIImagePicker but as I have attached image it's providing this image.

As you can see i have allowing editing of photo.

Now See Image what i crop and what this UIImagePickerView returning to me.

[image][image]

Comment: [self.view presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
instead of use like this         [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil]; and didfinish like this - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    
    UIImage *selectedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.selectedImgView.image = selectedImage;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
} and its working fine for me

Comment: @RajeshDharani this is impossible to read. If you're answering a question... add an answer. Not a comment.

Comment: @RajeshDharani i am using mostly same code no change same response.

Comment: Is it the same issue as here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630155/uiimagepicker-allowsediting-stuck-in-center

Comment: No @Fogmeister it's different issue.

Comment: You can try this: https://github.com/myang-git/iOS-Image-Crop-View

Comment: @hardikvyas check content aspect mode of UIImageView.

Comment: @AnandKore Actually i have tested and check it before set to uiimageview it's giving wrong image and this issue i have found all app which developed in latest version please check it in your current app also it may be there in your app also.

Answer (score -2):

So I think you want to cropped this image when set allowEditing YES.

If you don't want to edited this image, set allowEditing property NO.

When you get or edited this image,you need make this image in `UIPickerViewControllerDelegate` .Next method,

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
```

In this delegete method, you need to write code like this.

```
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];

    // edit image -- select type UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage
    // origin image --  UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage
    UIImage *generateImg = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    //and then operate this image.
```

You can try and test if the issue is resolved.If not you can ask again in here.

Comment: So you need change UIPickerViewControllerDelegate info ,set  UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage.This question that capture image move up wnen tap choose UIButton.

Comment: I passing a lot of testing when you post this question .Finally,I found the problem occured in system version over 11.0.When system version 11.0 or less,it's ok.I test in 11.3 and 10.3.So I think it because of system version in over 11.0.You can believe me or test yourself.

Comment: It's actually system issue i have tested in other app also at there and found there is same issue.